# Как передать в настройки логера уже открытый файл?

Tags: python, логирование

Можно ли передать в настройки логера уже открытый файл, а не имя файла?

Примерно так:

```
logging.basicConfig(file=open('file.txt'))
```

вместо:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='file.txt')
```

Comment: А Вы видите какие-то препятствия этому? Если вопрос со стороны целесообразности и на тему "стоит ли", то здесь рассуждать можно долго. А если с точки зрения возможностей языка, то почему нет?

Comment: @V-Mor препятствие -- отсутствие ключевого параметра `file` в документации :)

Comment: Аа, сращу не понял, что это встроенный тип. Ну, тогда Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Если в документации нет, значит нельзя. Можно написать обёртку для этого класса, но это немного задом наперёд получится.

Comment: @V-Mor нет, это обычный файл `io.textIOWrapper` или как он там называется. Другими словами, вместо строки `'file.txt'` мне надо передать в логгер `open('file.txt')`

Comment: `io.textIOWrapper` и есть встроенный тип. Я понял, что Вы хотите и говорю Вам: если в документации нет, то этого сделать нельзя. Разве что реализовать обёртку над модулем `logging`, принимающую открытый файл, получающую его имя и передающую его логгеру, но при этом ещё этот файл закрывающую, дабы логгер смог открыть. В общем, думаю, Вы сами слышите, как криво звучит это решение.

Comment: @V-Mor понял, а почему так? Метод делает какой-то дополнительный хендлинг при открытии, который не позволяет ему работать с уже открытым файлом?

Comment: А Вы внимательно читали документацию? Есть у меня тут кое-какие подозрения, минутку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функционал, который Вам нужен, реализуется через параметр `stream`. Ваш код можно переписать так:

```python
logging.basicConfig(stream=open('file.txt'))
```

P.S. Плоховато Вы, видно, читаете документацию :)